# Why does Google's Rich Results test find structured data that I don't see in the browser?

Tags: seo, json-ld, structured-data

Using https://search.google.com/test/rich-results I ran a test on this web page: https://www.cwcycles.co.za/product/sram-pc-gx-eagle-chain

It returns a found product, and on inspecting where that structured data is located it shows that there is a JSON-LD block in the head element: [image: snip of the price present in the JSON-LD block]

However, when I view the source for this page in Chrome there is no such block. Additionally I have inspected the page in the dev tools to see if JS is building it, and I have also changed the UserAgent to be GoogleBot, but still no luck in producing this JSON-LD block.

Why is it that Google's tool is seeing it but I am not?

Note: Originally I discovered this issue in a Python tool I have built, but have replicated it in the browser for ease of asking the question.

Comment: Using Chrome developer tools to inspect the page and I can see the structured data. No need to play with UA etc. Mobile and Desktop mode.

Comment: There is some structured data in the HTML; I see a span with a price property. But it is this JSON-LD block that I cannot see. You can see a script block of type ld+json?

Comment: Yes. I'd share a screenshot, but that requires an answer. Maybe you should try on other devices in other networks to narrow down things.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up Tony, I tried it on a different device and it worked! I'm going to investigate.

Comment: Figured it out Tony (I added an answer). Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was an ad blocker running on the network. This evidently interfered with the javascript needed to insert the structured data block (it was inserted on page load). Removing the ad blocker allowed me to see the data.

Comment: Good to known. As bots do not use ad blockers they should have always seen the structured data. Saying that, bots honour disallows in robots.txt which means they tend not to run tracking code and ad code. Always worth checking with their tools.